# How to log an ios display object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Sure I know how to log double, float, string, etc. For the life of me I don't know how to log a `delegate` or a `self` and google has proven to be *no help* in finding the answer.

eg `SomeLog(self.delegate);`

I'm trying to find out if self.delegate is already a non-null value. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `NSLog(@"%@", myObject);`. The `%@` is used for object types.

Comment: i tried `NSLog(@"%@", self);` and it worked like a champ. Thanks StuDev!